# Combining Querys

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq to Sql to get two lists than take Union with another list. They are working fine. But I am wondering if it can be done in one Query or two instead of three that I have.

**Querys are**

```
var l = (from t in T_list1
         where t.Date == DateTime.Today 
         select new 
         {   
             oldDate=t.OldDate,
             Name=t.name,
             Email=t.EmailAddress,
             list2TableId=t.l2Id,
             CustomerId=t.customerId
         });


var l2=(from d in T_list2
        from e in l1
        where d.Id == e.list2TableId
        select new
        {                
            Date=d.oldDate,
            CName=d.Name,
            Experience=e.experience,            
        });

list2.Dump();
var l3 = list2.Union(list3).ToList();
```

I was looking at this post but didnt work. [Combining 2 Linq queries into 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806232/combining-2-linq-queries-into-1)
Thanks for your input.

Comment: What is the problem with your code and why do you want to change it?

Comment: I suspect some typos but the posted code makes little sense. Please check l/l1/list1 and l2/list2

Answer (score 0):

You could do a join instead of the 2 queries:

```
         var l = (from t in T_list1
                  join d in T_list2 on t.l2Id equals d.Id
                 where t.Date == DateTime.Today 
                 select new 
                 {
                 oldDate=t.OldDate,
                 Name=t.name,
                 Email=t.EmailAddress,
                 list2TableId=t.l2Id,
                 CustomerId=t.customerId
                 Date=d.oldDate,
                 CName=d.Name
                 Experience=e.experience,
                 });
```

I haven't tested the query but it should show you the rough idea.

Have a look at JOINs in SQL & Linq to get more information.